# Преобразование Фурье, ищу библиотеку/решение/объяснение формулы

Tags: c#, фурье

Стоит задача применить преобразование Фурье на маленький ряд(12 значений)

Я так понял Быстрое преобразование Фурье не очень подходит, т.к. там требуется количество данных степени 2, а значит режет треть данных до 8 значений, что 
критично

Ищу либо готовое решение, либо пояснений по формуле, чтобы реализовать самому

В сети находил такую формулу

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Пробовал по ней считать, и потом сравнивал первые значения из [FFT с вики](https://ru.wikibooks.org/wiki/%D0%A0%D0%B5%D0%B0%D0%BB%D0%B8%D0%B7%D0%B0%D1%86%D0%B8%D0%B8_%D0%B0%D0%BB%D0%B3%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%B8%D1%82%D0%BC%D0%BE%D0%B2/%D0%91%D1%8B%D1%81%D1%82%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B5_%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%BE%D0%B1%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B7%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5_%D0%A4%D1%83%D1%80%D1%8C%D0%B5). Полученные мной значения сильно отличаются

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Значения ряда, что преобразую (6.6, 6.3, 6, 6.3, 6.6, 6.6, 7.2, 6.9, 6.9, 7.2, 6.3, 6)

Считал так: 6.6 * exp(-2*3.141592*1*0 / 12) + 6.3*exp(-2.3.141592*1*1 / 12) + ... и так перебираю все значения x и n меняется на единицу до 12 и все это суммирую, так получаю значение 78,9 что на скриншоте выше
Это я что то считаю неправильно, или реализация FFT с вики неправильное, или у FFT и не быстрого Фурье разные первые значения?

Прикрепляю реализацию формулы

```
public static Complex[] FT(Complex[] X)
        {
            int N = X.Length;
            Complex[] result = new Complex[N];
            for (int k = 0; k < N; k++)
            {
                for (int n = 0; n < N; n++)
                {
                    double arg = -2 * Math.PI * k * n/ N;
                    var complex = new Complex(Math.Cos(2 * Math.PI * k * n / N), Math.Sin(-2 * Math.PI * k * n / N));
                    result[k] += X[n] * complex;
                }
            }
            return result;
        }
```

Comment: А куда Вы при вычислениях дели мнимую единицу из приведенной формулы?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Для начала

> Алгоритм быстрого преобразования Фурье логично применять для N >> 1, потому как при малом числе отсчётов он даёт небольшой выигрыш в скорости по отношению к прямому расчёту дискретного преобразования Фурье.

Далее, в вашей формуле `j` - это мнимая единица. Куда вы ее дели в расчетах не ясно.

На той же [Вики](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%94%D0%B8%D1%81%D0%BA%D1%80%D0%B5%D1%82%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%B5_%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%BE%D0%B1%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B7%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5_%D0%A4%D1%83%D1%80%D1%8C%D0%B5) приведена ваша формула и формула вытекающая из нее

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Тут меня уже подводит математика, я так понимаю что вычитать i*sin из косинуса нельзя, т.к. там мнимое число и его нельзя смешивать с действительным, а квадратные скобки скобки раскрываем и получаем xn*cos() реальное число + (i*sin()) мнимое число, верно?

Comment: Нет. При раскрытии скобок получится комплексное число `x*cos(...) - i * x * sin(...)`. Два комплексных числа складываются по правилу `(a + bi) + (c + di) = (a + c) + (b + d)i`. Перемножаются `(a + bi) * (c + di) = ac +  adi + bci - bd = (ac - bd) + (ad + bc)i`

Comment: Ещё такой уточняющий вопрос, xn это действительное число(замер), для того чтобы умножить его на комплексное число, нам нужно его представить в виде комплексного числа? Т.е. `6.6*cos(...) - i *0*sin(...)` или обе части умножаются на это число `6.6*cos(...) - i*6.6* sin(...)`? В FFT на входе принимаются замеры как массив комплексных чисел, я их представлял как  `Complex(6.6, 0)`, возможно это было неправильно...

Comment: @StriBog Какая разница x действительное число или комплексное? Любое действительное число можно представить в виде комплексного `x + 0i`. А как перемножать комплексные числа я вам написал в комментарии выше